# Stored Procedures - Using Output as Input

Tags: sql

Can you use the output of a stored procudure again in the same stored procedure? and if so how? As an example, I input a customer name and it returns a customerID. however, I need to use that customerID to return information from another table. How would I do this without creating another stored procedure?

Comment: what dmbs are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, e.g. if you use nested queries

For example,

```
SELECT ANOTHER_TABLE.FEILD 
FROM ANOTHER_TABLE 
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM TABLE_1 WHERE CUSTOMER_NAME = 'NAME')
```